# Heroku Can't Launch Python Flask App (" AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'uses_netloc' ")

Tags: python, postgresql, function, heroku, web-deployment

I'm trying to get a heroku app deployed and unfortunately I am getting the following error. Essentially what the Heroku logs tell you to do to get a heroku database connection is the following (taken from here; https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql)

```
import os
import psycopg2
import urlparse

urlparse.uses_netloc.append("postgres")
url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database=url.path[1:],
    user=url.username,
    password=url.password,
    host=url.hostname,
    port=url.port
)
```

I started using gunicorn, but I couldn't understand the errors that I was getting because it was spawning like 10 workers, so I switched to waitress and I got the following error (from `heroku logs`):

```
2017-07-16T22:21:52.941072+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread Thread-1:
2017-07-16T22:21:52.941072+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-07-16T22:21:52.941073+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
2017-07-16T22:21:52.941073+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.run()
2017-07-16T22:21:52.941073+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
2017-07-16T22:21:52.941074+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
2017-07-16T22:21:52.941074+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/timed/inflation.py", line 28, in inflatemethod
2017-07-16T22:21:52.941075+00:00 app[web.1]:     urlparse.uses_netloc.append("postgres")
2017-07-16T22:21:52.941075+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'uses_netloc'
```

So by default the heroku method that is in the docs is broken! That is bad! I'm not sure how to fix this, does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting the same error on Python 3 with gunicorn. Hmm...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown your actual code from inflation.py. In that code, you are almost certainly doing `from urlparse import urlparse`, instead of importing the *module* as in the example code.

Comment: How would I go about translating this to Python 3? `from urllib.parse import urlparse`, right?

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3 the urlparse library is now urllib.parse

So the Heroku sample is good for Python 2 apps however for Python 3 apps the following changes should work:

```
import urllib.parse

urllib.parse.uses_netloc.append("postgres")
url = urllib.parse.urlparse(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, you need to use `urllib.parse` instead of `urlparse`.

```
import urllib.parse

urllib.parse.uses_netloc.append('postgres')
url = urllib.parse.urlparse(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])
```

instead of

```
import urlparse

urlparse.uses_netloc.append("postgres")
url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])
```